# Can't debug node, with nodemon, dockerfile and docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging, nodemon

I've tried a lot of things, read a lot of articles, sometimes my debug doesn't even work, and when it does, my application NEVER stops in my breakpoint while I'm running my application with docker, if I delete the launch.json and run my application outside docker, just running "node app.js" , I can debug normally.

I'm sorry if this is an obviously thing to do, I'm really struggling to do it.

SO I'd be glad if anyone could give me any guidance.

This is my package.json

```
 "name": "ahgorastrainer",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "app.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 app.js"
 },
 "author": "Pedro Verani",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
   "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
   "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
   "ejs": "^3.1.2",
   "express": "^4.17.1",
   "express-session": "^1.17.1",
   "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
   "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
   "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
 }
}
```

Docker-compose

```
 version: '3'

services:
  ahgora-strainer:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
```

Docker File

```
 FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Launch Json (Here's where I've tried a billion of differente configs)

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "port": 9229,
            "name": "strainer",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
            "restart": true,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "timeout": 99999999
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: I usually attach to the process running in chrome dev tools (open about:inspect in chrome). What tool are you using to attach to the docker node (remote) process?

Comment: Don't even know what are u talking about

Comment: How are you connecting to debug? What tools or commands are you running and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

When running a node application in a container, it must be debugged as a remote node process. Thus you need to attach to the process. Chrome makes this process relatively easy (once it is setup). 
The way I usually do this:

Set my package.json normally with something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
```

install nodemon in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN npm install -g nodemon@1.19.1
```

Finally in the docker-compose:

```
  mynodeapp:
    build: ./nodeApp
    container_name: mynodemultidb
    command: nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858
    volumes:
      - ./nodeApp:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5858:5858"
      - "3000:3000"
```

After that bring the app up with `docker-compose up`
Open the app in Google chrome by going to `localhost:3000` (or whatever port you have exposed)
Open a new tab and navigate to `about:inspect`
Your application should show in the Remote target section. 
[image: Chrome inspector opened]

Click the inspect link.
That opens the dev tools attached to the code.

[image: Dev tools opened]
Click the link to the source code at the right side of the page (index.js:37 in the picture above).
That opens the code and it is now possible to put break points as needed
[image: debugging code]

Go back to the tab running your app and refresh it to activate the debugging.